# Can QGIS Web Client be used with SQL Server based QGIS project?

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, qgis-web-client

question:  We are running a QGIS project with the majority of data coming from a SQL Server 2008 database as well as some third party WMS feeds.

Will QGIS Server and QGIS Web Client be compatible with data originating from a SQL Server database and accept WMS feeds not generated by the QGIS Server?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If QGIS can read and display the SQL Server 2008 data (or any WMS layers), then you should be able to serve up the data from QGIS Server to QGIS Web Client.

Comment: how about searching?  Sounds like its been figured out for postgres...is it just some modifications for you SQL Server?

Comment: That would be a question for the guys over at sourcepole http://www.sourcepole.com/about_us  Some of them are users of this site.  It can (most likely) be made to work with SQL Server 2008 but they'll probably need to do some code modification.  Good luck.